# Hash Sum mismatch while installing bcmwl-kernel-source

Tags: networking, drivers, broadcom

I am new to ubuntu , i have installed ubuntu in dual boot with windows 10 in dell laptop. 
my problem is - **not able to see wi-fi networks / options**.
i tried to install ' bcmwl-kernel-source' (tried to resolve the issue of install wifi drivers) i am getting '**Hash Sum mismatch**'

i followed the answer - [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Can anyone tell me , what mistake i did ?

below is the complete log

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree    
Reading state information... Done    
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  bcmwl-kernel-source    
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 45 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,515 kB of archives.    
After this operation, 8,013 kB of additional disk space will be used.    
Get:1 archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted amd64 bcmwl-kernel-source amd64 6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu8 [1,515 kB]    
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted amd64 bcmwl-kernel-source amd64 6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu8    
  Hash Sum mismatch
Fetched 1,515 kB in 19s (78.0KB/s)                                            
E: Failed to fetch archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu8_amd64.deb  
  Hash Sum mismatch 
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: Are you using secure boot? And is this Ubuntu 16.04? You should be able to install the drivers through the additional drivers tab then, but your kernel might prevent them from working as they're not trusted.

Comment: @Tobias - i disabled the secure boot while installing Ubuntu.

Comment: @Anwar - I followed the answer of the question you mentioned , but still i am facing the same error. I believe the cause is different in my case.

Comment: Do first `sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/*` then `sudo apt update`. then install it

Comment: @Anwar - rm: cannot remove '/var/lib/apt/lists/partial': Is a directory             this Error i am getting  when i tried the above cmd.

Comment: That's not a problem. proceed to other commands

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions guys, Now the issue is resolved. I  reinstalled again . might be the secure boot only causing the issue.  Anyway thanks to you all , i am able to access wi-fi n/w through ubuntu. :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you first confirm that you have a working internet connection:

```
ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com
```

If so, then next:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Post any errors.

Comment: Thanks for the Quick response  , but this time also i am getting same error, please check below Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted amd64 bcmwl-kernel-source amd64 6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu8
  Hash Sum mismatch
Fetched 1,483 kB in 16s (88.6 kB/s)                                            
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu8_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Comment: I am not sure about your update , but this time also same error  -                         Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted amd64 bcmwl-kernel-source amd64 6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu8
  Hash Sum mismatch
Fetched 487 kB in 22min 18s (364 B/s)                                          
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu8_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

Comment: The edit to my answer to to add the first step, `sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/*` Did you do that *first* and then all the remaining steps in order?

Comment: Issue is resolved by re-intsalling , Thank you.